# C# - require a returned type to be assigned to an L-Value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lvalue, ienumerator

this may not be sensible,
but i'm looking at a situation where i would like it to be a compile error if the return value of a method goes unused.

specifically, Unity3D implements coroutines which look like this:

```
IEnumerator myCoroutine() {...  yield break;}
```

if you call `myCoroutine()` and do nothing with the returned value (eg, you're calling it like a normal method, not from inside another yield clause or via the StartCoroutine() method), the result is that all the code inside myCoroutine() is not executed. *however*, there is no compile- or runtime- warning.  i would like to get a compile-time error in this scenario.

one approach i thought of is to subclass IEnumerator into say MyIEnumerator, which adds the property that it must be passed on in some way - either assigned to an L-Value or passed to a method, etc.

but i haven't been able to discover if such a requirement exists.

Comment: How are you calling the `myCoroutine` function? Also how do you know the code inside it is not executing? Put `Debu.Log` inside it to very your statement.

Comment: @Programmer As he said, if someone calls a method that returns an `IEnumerable` implemented with an iterator block, and then never iterates it, the iterator code never runs.  You can write such a program yourself if you want, it's pretty clear behavior.

Comment: @Programmer, i know the code does not execute because i tested it with logging.  I'm calling the coroutine how i described: like a normal method, not like a coroutine.  I would like to get a compile-time error in this case to let me know i've made a mistake.

Comment: Ok. Didn't understand the question at first.

Comment: just curious, why the downvotes ?  it seems like a legit question, and i did look through the [C# docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx) prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature in C# for this.  You'd need to create some form of 3rd party code analysis tool to try to look for cases such as these.

Comment: i did some light searching for a linter or similar, but came up empty. that's sort of what i figured. thanks for the definitive answer.